# Lua unit tests for Android code

Tags: android, lua

I have a question. Can I develop some unit tests in Lua in order to test an Android application or does Lua unit testing only apply to Lua code? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lua unit testing only applies to Lua code.

However, you can still do Lua unit tests if you develop your android application in Lua.

You could, for example, use the [corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) to do that.

Another (more difficult, less expensive) way to do that would be to use Lua directly from Java, for example with [luajava](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/manual.html), [luaj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaj/), [kahlua](http://code.google.com/p/kahlua/) or [mochalua](http://code.google.com/p/mochalua/). In that case, you would be able to test the Lua parts with Lua unit tests, but you would have to use something else for the Java part (something like JUnit)